# I can't drag and drop emails in Microsoft format MSG into Outlook 2013

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2013

I have 20 emails which i wanted to take backup, i took all emails drag and drop from outlook to windows explorer and all messages are .msg
now i deleted all the messages from the server and need to took them from widows explorer to outlook 2013 to upload them again to the server
all the answers say drag and drop from windows explorer to outlook but when i do that this message appears

```
Creating a new item from the selected items could take some time…are you sure you want to create a new item from these items…?
```

if i said no , nothing happen but if i say yes it opens a new message and mage the selected messages which i drag as attachment

is there a way to get all my messages back to outlook if i have .msg emails in a folder?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the free [Import Messages from MSG Files](http://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookMessagesImportMSG) for that. It has to work without any problems and you can place the buttons for exporting and importing MSGs right on your Outlook ribbon to make the backup-restore procedure much easier.

DISCLAIMER: I recommend this tools because I'm one of the developers, so feel free to ask any further questions.

Comment: link isn't working

Comment: It has to work now.

Answer (score 0):

- Drag 'n drop the `.MSG` files into [Windows Live Mail](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/essentials) (evolution of Outlook Express)
- Drag 'n drop from Windows Live Mail to Outlook.

Comment: can't setup it, every time get error that it can't complete instalation

Comment: Try installing as administrator. Right click on installer and select run as administrator